# Displaying "description" from an RSS feed in an iOS app

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser, rss-reader

I am trying to create an Simple RSS reader , i would like to fetch the "`description`" tag from the rss feed and display it in my app , any help ?

Is it advisable to use `NSXMLParser` or any other parser to make my work easy ?

The Source code i am using is from : [iOS programming RSS reader tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-rss-reader-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What else left with that tutorial . Everything works fine na. They
>   just left to use the Description item . right ...?

Here goes from that tutorial :

```
@interface ViewController (){

 NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableArray *feeds;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSMutableString *title;
    NSMutableString *link;
    NSString *element;

 NSMutableString *desc; // Description .
}
```

**Just paste this code . Works like charm :**

```
#pragma mark - parsing of RssFeed Values

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        title = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        link = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        desc = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];  
    }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];
        [item setObject:desc forKey:@"description"];
        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

    }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];
    }else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]){
        [link appendString:string];
    }else if ([element isEqualToString:@"description"]){
        [desc appendString:string];
    }
}


-(void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

> Use this parameter **Desc** anywhere to get the Description of the
>   RSSFeed item.

Here is completion of it :

```
-(void) tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"description"];

    stringUrl = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"link"];
     NSLog(@"Description %@", string);

   actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:string delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:Nil destructiveButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"GoTo URL", nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
{
  self.actionSheet.delegate = self;
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
              NSLog(@"ButtonIndex at 0");
                break;

        case 1:
             NSLog(@"ButtonIndex at 1");
           //Add your Segue functionalities over here to open link on the browser .

    }
                break;
        } 

}
```

> If you have any problem here , Plz let me know :::

Comment: using " %@ " fro the string displays all the contents of the Feed , including the link and description. I need to display only the description , is there any other way possible ?

Comment: only description. The current o/p is like : "the URL of the Feed" followed by the description.

Comment: i tried excluding the URL using RegEX but , also have other URL those should be shown to user , so that idea didn't work out .

Comment: **didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** This method take care of the Selection item data . You just need to show properly by using **Desc** array .